# Hi, I can't seem to understand how one works with ids in kivy and python

Tags: python, kivy

Basically I've got a button and when you press it and once a certain condition has been met, another button should "disappear" (by reducing it's size_hint to 0). But it doesn't work and tells me that 'NormalGame' object has no attribute 'v1'.
Any and all help is welcome, thank you!

Here's the button in the kv file:

---

```
<NormalGame>:
    name: "ngame"
    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            id: v1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.66, "y": 0.725}
            size_hint: (0.01, 0.01)
            text: "V"
            on_release:
                root.btn_action_v1()
```

---

### And here's the py file:

```
class NormalGame(Screen):  
    def btn_action_v1(self):
        v1 = self.ids.v1
        if players_combination == colour_combination:
            print("you won")
        else:
            players_combination.clear()
            self.v1.size_hint = 0, 0
```

---

### Here's the error code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:/Users/edgar/Desktop/python projects/flappy bird/main.py", line 725, in <module>
     MyMainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\edgar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "c:\Users\edgar\Desktop\python projects\flappy bird\rls.kv", line 139, in <module>
     root.btn_action_v1()
   File "c:/Users/edgar/Desktop/python projects/flappy bird/main.py", line 684, in btn_action_v1
     self.v1.size_hint = 0, 0
 AttributeError: 'NormalGame' object has no attribute 'v1'
```

---

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute `v1` of the `NormalGame`, but there is a local variable `v1` that you have created. Try changing:

```
self.v1.size_hint = 0, 0
```

to:

```
v1.size_hint = 0, 0
```